# Ajax not appending to my drop down list (C# MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I'm busy with 2 drop downs. The first one is country and loads fine, then on country change I call ajax to populate the province drop down.

The code works fine and when I put an alert in my ajax call it shows the correct data being created but it doesn't append it the drop down so the values aren't available.

Drop Down

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-5 control-label">Country:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-7">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CountryId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.CountryItems, "Please Select", new { @id = "ddlCountry", @class = "form-control select" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-5 control-label">Province:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-7">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ProvinceId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Please Select", new { @id = "ddlProvince", @class = "form-control select" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The Ajax

```
<script>
    $('#ddlCountry').change(function () {
        var countries = document.getElementById("ddlCountry");
        var countryId = countries.options[countries.selectedIndex].value;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Master/GetProvinces",
            data: { countryId: countryId },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            error: function () {
                alert(" An error occurred.");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i) {
                    var optionhtml = '<option value="' + data[i].Value + '">' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
                    $("#ddlProvince").append(optionhtml);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The code behind

```
 public ActionResult GetProvinces(string countryId)
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ProvinceItems = null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(countryId))
        {
            ProvinceItems = BusinessAPI.ProvinceManager.GetAllProvincesByCountryId(Convert.ToInt32(countryId)).Select(ci => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = ci.Id.ToString(),
                Text = ci.Name
            });
        }

        return Json(ProvinceItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Can you confirm with a `console.log` of the variable `optionhtml` that it is getting constructed correctly?

Comment: Can you show the resulting html of the part of the view that you showed us?

Comment: I get a list populated like this - <option value="1">FreeState</option>

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. 
I have a javascript file in there thats causing some issues.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
```

This came with the template I bought and it helps with the way the dropdowns and stuff works.

With that javascript file you have to add .selectpicker('refresh'); to the append to load it properly like this

```
$("#ddlProvince").append(optionshtml).selectpicker('refresh');
```

That might be slow when loading a large amount of data so just refreshing the dropdown once after everything done works well. Here is the code that works well for me now

```
$('#ddlCountry').change(function () {
        var countries = document.getElementById("ddlCountry");
        var countryId = countries.options[countries.selectedIndex].value;

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Master/GetProvinces",
            data: { countryId: countryId },
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            error: function () {
                alert(" An error occurred.");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                ("#ddlProvince").empty();
                $.each(data, function (i) {
                    var optionshtml = '<option value="' + data[i].Value + '">' + data[i].Text + '</option>';
                    $("#ddlProvince").append(optionshtml);
                });
                $("#ddlProvince").selectpicker('refresh');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: doing $("#ddlProvince").append(optionshtml); everytime in a loop would make it slow instead use my below answered changes for filling ddl.

Comment: Also If you change country more than once with above code the province ddl contain all province from changed countries.